# selecting multiple records from database by interval of integers in java

Tags: java, database, select, derby

How can I select from derby database by interval of integers? Can it be done more effectively than using for cycle, incrementing an int and trying to select record from database for every int from interval? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A query like this should do it:

```
select * 
from mytable
where some_column between ? and ?
```

Derby uses JDBC and SQL, so you can create a query with placeholders (question mark) for the variable then supply values at runtime via `query.setInt(1, 3)`  and `query.setInt(2, 7)` for example to get the range of 3 to 7 (inclusive),

Answer (score 0):

Do it on the database side, eg doing SQL like this will only give you each 3rd row. (It is assumed you have a table called `mytable` with primary key column `id`)

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id % 3 = 0
```

Comment: any idea how can i do that?